# Use a Video as Landing Page background (as seen in Spotify, Twitter or Vine)

Tags: ios, video, background

I'd like to set a video as background to a view. I found multiple solutions, each one with great drawbacks, like:

1. Using `MPMoviePlayerController`, it works ok. The video has the best quality, however it uses a lot of cpu (~50% on my mac). I didn't dare to test it on my phone.
2. Converting the video to a .gif and displaying it with a `UIWebView`. This is a great solution, but i couldn't make a high quality gif. The video has lots of movement which is not suited for gif files.

Is there a better solution? I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Never assume performance without testing. Keep in mind that iOS is optimized for the device. I've often found performance to be much better on a device than on the simulator.

Comment: You were right! On my device it uses about 0-1% and 5MB memory. Still, i'll leave this question open in case someone has some better solutions.

Comment: Im currently using .gif and it consumes a large amount of CPU.

Comment: Hi Danut Mihai, how did you managed the different video ratio between different devices? (i.e iphone 4 and iphone 5 which have different screen ratio)
Thanks :)

Comment: @ApheX hey! I didn't set the video as full page, but centered it with auto layout constraints. I think it looks better this way. Also you could use some constraints to set it full screen and crop the extra areas.

Answer (score 1):

I did that before using `AVPlayer`. It was since iOS 4 (long time ago), and it didn't cause any noticeable effect on the performance.